# Are any missions mutually exclusive?

Tags: mass-effect-3

This is a pretty simple one. **Are there any missions in the game that are mutually exclusive?** That is, are there any two or more missions that are uncompletable in a single playthrough?

For example, say the missions *Kill Guys #5*, *Fetch Quest #11*, and *Planet Scanner #19* are available to complete. When I finish mission *Fetch Quest #11*, mission *Kill Guys #5* becomes unavailable. However, at the same time, if I finish *Kill Guys #5*, mission *Fetch Quest #11* becomes unavailable. Therefore, it's impossible to complete *Kill Guys #5* and *Fetch Quest #11* in a single playthrough due to the missions canceling each other out.

**Are there any actual scenarios like the example above in the game?**

Comment: There have never been missions in mass effect which are mutually exclusieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope. As long as you complete the timed missions and other side missions before Priority missions, you won't miss any.

Comment: any proof? -1 till you do.

Comment: not really he doesnt even say if he has completed the game or anything just says no.

Comment: @Paralytic: The only mission I didn't complete was the side mission on Eden Prime, and that's only because it becomes locked out after leaving with Javik.  Is it possible that I didn't acquire every mission on the Citadel?  Sure, but in previous games you didn't receive missions that were mutually exclusive, and I haven't seen evidence for that in ME3.

Comment: @Para That's an interesting point. The in-game Journal is absolutely no help at telling you if you've done everything.

Comment: I tried editing the answer and adding his comment but i think it was disapproved by the moderators